# Oracle SQL Count Children and Parents by Date and ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hierarchical-data

**Background:** I need a way to count the number of records that we will be running through our Archive process. The query I have below what I have come up with but I feel like there has to be a better way (Takes about 20minutes to run for the last 90 days)

**The Query**: We have a table called Table_Main (Not its real name) which contains alot of records (300 million +) and is constantly being added to (Hence the archiving). The table contains parent records that have a TR_ID, which links them to another table, while the children do not have a TR_ID. The children are attached to the parents via a Parent_ID. The tricky part here is that I need to count the records based of values contained in the Trans table which is linked via TR_ID.

```
 Select  B.Some_date, B.xx_ID, count(*)
From
(
select tr.Some_date, tr.xx_ID, p.H_ID
from Table_Main p, Trans tr
where p.TR_ID = tr.TR_ID 
 and tr.Some_date>sysdate-90
     --
UNION ALL
        --
Select Result.Some_date , Result.xx_ID, th.H_ID
from (
select tr.Some_date, tr.xx_ID, p.H_ID
from Table_Main p, Trans tr
where p.TR_ID = tr.TR_ID  and tr.Some_date>sysdate-90
) Result
  inner join Table_Main th on th.Parent_id = Result.H_ID and th.Parent_ID is not null
  ) B
  group by  B.Some_date, B.xx_ID
order by B.Some_date;
```

**Question/Idea**: Is there any way this could be simplified with one join between Table_Main and itself? For example a join that keeps the first record from the parent plus all the joined children? I was trying something like the query below but not getting anywhere.

```
Select a.Some_date, A.xx_ID, p.H_ID, c.*
from Table_Main p
inner join Trans a on p.TR_ID = a.TR_ID
left join Table_Main c on c.Parent_id = p.H_ID 
where a.Some_date> sysdate-20
order by p.H_ID, c.H_ID
```

Table_Main

```
-H_ID
-Parent_ID //Links child to parent
-TR_ID     //Links to Trans Table
```

Trans

```
-TR_ID     //Link to Table_Main
-xx_ID     //This is used to group on
-Some_Date //Used to group on
```

**Sample Input:**

Table_Main

```
H_ID     Parent_ID     TR_ID
1        NULL          1
2        1             NULL
3        NULL          2
4        NULL          3
5        4             NULL
6        4             NULL
7        NULL          4
8        7             NULL
9        NULL          5
10       9             NULL
11       9             NULL
12       9             NULL
13       9             NULL
14       9             NULL
15       9             NULL
16       9             NULL
```

Trans

```
TR_ID    XX_ID    Some_Date
1        45       12/1/2015
2        4        12/1/2015
3        6        12/20/2015
4        45       12/1/2015
5        23       12/22/2015
```

Desired Output:

```
Date      xx_ID Count
12/1/2015   4   1
12/1/2015   45  4
12/20/2015  6   3
12/22/2015  23  8
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: table structrue,input and desired output would help us.

Comment: @sagi Added structure and desired output.

Comment: Some sample input data that produces your expected output would help a lot.

Comment: @Boneist Added input data as well as expected output. I can expand if you would like to see more results

Comment: Why does the row `12/1/2015   45  4` have a count of 4? There is one matching row in the `Trans` table which connects to one parent and one child row in the `Table_main` table so the count ought to be 2.

Comment: @MT0 I fixed the date on one of the records in the Trans table that had 2016 instead of 2015. The row in question has a count of 4 because records 1,2,7 and 8 are all connected to that date and xx_ID. xx_ID is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the input and expected output data - that makes it a lot easier for us to make sure we have the answer you're expecting!

Here's one way of doing it:

```
with table_main as (select 1 H_ID, null Parent_ID, 1 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 2 H_ID, 1 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 3 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 2 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 4 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 3 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 5 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 6 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 7 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 4 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 8 H_ID, 7 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 9 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 5 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 10 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 11 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 12 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 13 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 14 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 15 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 16 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual),
          trans as (select 1 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 2 TR_ID, 4 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 3 TR_ID, 6 XX_ID, to_date('12/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 4 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 5 TR_ID, 23 XX_ID, to_date('12/22/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables with data in them. See SQL below:                    
select   tr1.some_date,
         tr1.xx_id,
         count(*) cnt
from     (select     h_id,
                     parent_id,
                     max(tr_id) over (partition by connect_by_root(h_id)) tr_id
          from       table_main tm
          connect by prior h_id = parent_id
          start with parent_id is null) tm1
         inner join trans tr1 on (tm1.tr_id = tr1.tr_id)
group by tr1.some_date,
         tr1.xx_id
order by tr1.some_date,
         tr1.xx_id;

SOME_DATE       XX_ID        CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
12/01/2015          4          1
12/01/2015         45          4
12/20/2015          6          3
12/22/2015         23          8
```

Basically this first does a hierarchical query (`connect by...`) to link the parent and child rows.

Then we use the `connect_by_root` function to identify the top level h_id across all the parent-child rows.

Once we have that, we can then use an analytic function to return the tr_id across all the parent and child rows per each top level h_id (I've used max() here, as it looks like only parent rows will have a tr_id).

Then it's a simple matter of joining to the trans table and doing the aggregate count.

---

Here's a (hopefully faster!) modified way of doing the same thing, given that there are only two possible levels of the hierarchy:

```
with table_main as (select 1 H_ID, null Parent_ID, 1 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 2 H_ID, 1 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 3 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 2 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 4 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 3 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 5 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 6 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 7 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 4 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 8 H_ID, 7 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 9 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 5 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 10 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 11 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 12 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 13 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 14 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 15 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 16 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual),
          trans as (select 1 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 2 TR_ID, 4 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 3 TR_ID, 6 XX_ID, to_date('12/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 4 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 5 TR_ID, 23 XX_ID, to_date('12/22/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables with data in them. See SQL below:                    
select   tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id,
         count(*) cnt
from     table_main tm1
         left join table_main tm2 on (tm1.h_id = coalesce(tm2.parent_id, tm2.h_id) and tm1.parent_id is null)
         inner join trans tr on (tm1.tr_id = tr.tr_id)
group by tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id
order by tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id;

SOME_DATE       XX_ID        CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
12/01/2015          4          1
12/01/2015         45          4
12/20/2015          6          3
12/22/2015         23          8
```

---

Another possible answer that doesn't involve a self join, but does rely on analytic functions:

```
with table_main as (select 1 H_ID, null Parent_ID, 1 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 2 H_ID, 1 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 3 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 2 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 4 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 3 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 5 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 6 H_ID, 4 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 7 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 4 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 8 H_ID, 7 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 9 H_ID, NULL Parent_ID, 5 TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 10 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 11 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 12 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 13 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 14 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 15 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual union all
                    select 16 H_ID, 9 Parent_ID, NULL TR_ID from dual),
          trans as (select 1 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 2 TR_ID, 4 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 3 TR_ID, 6 XX_ID, to_date('12/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 4 TR_ID, 45 XX_ID, to_date('12/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual union all
                    select 5 TR_ID, 23 XX_ID, to_date('12/22/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Some_Date from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables with data in them. See SQL below:                    
select   tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id,
         count(*) cnt
from     (select max(tr_id) over (partition by coalesce(parent_id, h_id)) tr_id
          from   table_main) tm1
         inner join trans tr on (tm1.tr_id = tr.tr_id)
group by tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id
order by tr.some_date,
         tr.xx_id;

SOME_DATE       XX_ID        CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
12/01/2015          4          1
12/01/2015         45          4
12/20/2015          6          3
12/22/2015         23          8
```

Comment: So I ran this and although it did get the correct results it took 3hours 32minutes to complete. I've tried using connect by in the past and always found it very slow. Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Hmm, not good! If there are no grandchild records, then another option might be a left outer join from table_main back to itself. I'll take another look at this tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: There are no grandchild records. The parent is really just a summary record for all the children so there will only ever be one. I was trying the left outer join approach but I needed it to count the parents and the children, not just the children. Hopefully you can figure this one out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you outer join the whole table to just the parent records, you'll get both parents and child records. Could you have a parent without any children? If not, then the join could be an inner join.

Comment: @Boniest,  Yes a parent could have no children.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to include the alternative answer involving a self outer join on the table_main. Hopefully that runs a bit faster for you! As an aside, what indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: Added a third solution; you may benefit from an index on (coalesce(parent_id, h_id), tr_id) for this one.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANS(
  TR_ID     NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  XX_ID     NUMBER(10,0),
  Some_Date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_MAIN (
  H_ID      NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  PARENT_ID NUMBER(10,0) REFERENCES TABLE_MAIN( H_ID ),
  TR_ID     NUMBER(10,0) REFERENCES TRANS( TR_ID )
);

INSERT INTO TRANS
SELECT 1, 45, DATE '2015-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  4, DATE '2015-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  6, DATE '2015-12-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 45, DATE '2015-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 23, DATE '2015-12-22' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO TABLE_MAIN
SELECT  1, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, NULL, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 7, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, NULL, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 9, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT some_date,
       xx_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   Trans t
       INNER JOIN
       (
        SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( TR_ID ) AS TR_ID
        FROM   Table_Main
        START WITH H_ID IS NOT NULL
        CONNECT BY PRIOR H_ID = PARENT_ID
       ) m
       ON ( t.TR_ID = m.TR_ID )
WHERE  some_date > SYSDATE - 90
GROUP BY some_date,
         xx_id;
```

**Results**:

```
SOME_DATE      XX_ID   COUNT(*)
--------- ---------- ----------
01-DEC-15          4          1 
01-DEC-15         45          4 
22-DEC-15         23          8 
20-DEC-15          6          3
```

Comment: I updated the question with input and desired output. I am trying to count the number of records in Table_Main not the number in Trans